# Is there a design pattern to handle two parallel iterators in constant memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a Rails action to stream data where the resulting CSV / XML / JSON file is much larger than the memory limit for the web server.  The tricky part is that each item in the dataset is composed from two sources.  One is a Postgres DB where I plan to open a CURSOR (or just use id > Y LIMIT X) to batch process the data.  The latter is a custom data store but there is basically a cursor object I can use to batch that as well.

My problem is I'm not sure what the best way to iterate over the second data source is.  I imagine I'll need a structure to open the cursor and as I consume the data in each batch I'll load the next batch.

This problem seems like it might have been solved already so I'm hoping there's an established pattern I can use.

Comment: One way to do it is to delegate the task to a worker process, separate from the web server, and have it signal back upon completion.

Comment: I'm not sure about the parallel management, but you could look at the [Batch Iterator pattern described in POSA vol.5](http://books.google.ca/books?id=wzplRf3uh-EC&lpg=PA174&ots=OnlrQ3T-nV&dq=allintext%3A%22batch%20iterator%22&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q=allintext:%22batch%20iterator%22&f=false)